# how to configure IBM websphere application server 7.0 with netbeans IDE 7.4

Tags: java, websphere, netbeans-7

Previously I used RAD 7.5 IDE and there i used Websphere Application Server(WAS) 7.0 to deploy my web projects.
Now I am moving to Netbeans IDE 7.4.
Could you please let me know how can I configure WAS 7.0 in Netbeans IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know only WAS Community Edition is supported for now by version 7 (not sure about 7.4)
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40546/wasce-plugin

There were old plugins for WAS 6.1 for Netbeans 6....

So the only way is to use some scripts for deployment or maybe maven plugin via Maven or Gradle if your project build around them. For debug purpose you can use remote debugger. I think that is all Netbeans can propose....

Comment: I tried to add plugin in netbeans 7.4 which was given by you. But it replied as it is not found. Does it supports in version 7.4?

Comment: As mentioned in documentation only versions 7.0 and 7.1 of Netbeans are supported.

Comment: Could you please gice a suggestion on how can I go with Webspehre Application server in netbeans7.4?

Comment: This is how to enable remote debugger on Websphere: http://www.mkyong.com/websphere/remote-debugging-with-eclipse-websphere-7

Comment: And here is the example of remote debugging with Netbeans http://forums.netbeans.org/topic29365.html. The last thing is to make an autodeploy.